# Database Connection Always disconnect when Developing on same PC as DB

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am developing a JSP application and I used Oracle Express 10g as database. I notice when I try to develop in the same PC, I would only be able to make several page request and transition and I immediately get IO exceptions. But I download the same code in a different PC and connect to the said database PC. It does not kick me out immediately. Any Idea if there is any other settings that needs to be set here?

Im using Apache Tomcat 5.5 and Eclipse as IDE.

```
[ 2009/10/05 17:59:02   The error occurred by XXXClass. ]
java.sql.SQLException: I/O Exception。: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:115)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:221)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:293)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:646)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1057)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1139)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1471)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3874)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3944)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:3613)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:93)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PC with the database isn't by any chance configured to get it's IP via DHCP, is it? If so you need to install the [Microsoft Loopback Adapter](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/html/B10130_02/reqs.htm#sthref340).

Comment: Yes my PC is configured to get IP via DHCP. I followed the instructions on adding the Microsoft Loopback Adapter and it worked. Thanks.